# Find a cell with Today's date in C4:V4 and paste content into cells below

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to figure out how to write a code that would :

- copy contents of Array A,
- look into Array B at the headers with dates,
- find current date
- and paste the contents directly beneath that cell.

So far the best I managed to achieve was have a macro find the date if I typed today's date specifically.

Edit: I was trying to repurpose a record macro and while the first time I recorded the same macro it worked, the next times it didn't all of sudden.

```
Sub Macro1()
Dim myDate As String
myDate = Format(Date, DDMMYYY)
Range("A5:A11").Select
Selection.Copy

Range("Table29[[#Headers],[23/01/2017]:[11/02/2017]]").Select
Selection.Find(What:="25/01/2017", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas _
    , LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate

    Range(ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0), ActiveCell.Offset(7, 0)).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

End Sub
```

Also I'm not sure but I feel like I was lacking some reference to activate `Date` function in VBA because whenever I try to use it I keep getting errors, even when I try to replicate other codes I found on google with `Date` in them.

Edit 2: I managed to get as far as paste stuff into desired array, but I still struggle to make `Date` work. If I don't manually type in the date, it won't work.

Comment: Can you please add the code that you have? http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I have posted and somewhat worked on it. I'm still struggling with the final part. Do you know what could be causing such issue?

Edit: Nevermind. Fixed it. It works now, success!